# Default sorting option not working in magento 2.2.7?

Tags: magento2, product-list, product-sorting, sort-by-options

I am using the default sorting option as product name but when the page loads for first time it is not working. It's only working when selecting an option from the sorting dropdown.

Comment: How have you configured? Stores > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Product Listing Sort By?

Comment: Yes i did the above config change but not working